# Time complexity of LinkedList in dart

Tags: dart, linked-list, time-complexity, big-o

In the dart [documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-collection/LinkedList-class.html) it is said that inserting a value in the middle of the list has constant time complexity but I was reading [this](https://medium.com/@mckenziefiege/arrays-linked-lists-and-big-o-notation-486727b6259b) article and as provided it is said that inserting a value in the middle of the list has the complexity of O(n), does dart handle the LinkedList in a different way?
[image]

Comment: I think you have skipped at lot of the Dart documentation if your conclusion are "inserting a value in the middle of the list has constant time complexity". It is constant if you have this element in hand where you then want to add the new element to the right/left of this current element. But to get this element, you would need to traverse though the existing elements which makes it `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is said that inserting a value in the middle of the list has constant time complexity

That is not true if you are reading the documentation more closely. What the documentation states are:

> ... Despite its name, this class does not implement the List interface. It does not allow constant time lookup by index.
>
> ...
>
> In return, each element knows its own place in the linked list, as well as which list it is in. This allows constant time `LinkedListEntry.insertAfter`, `LinkedListEntry.insertBefore` and `LinkedListEntry.unlink` operations when all you have is the element.
>
> A LinkedList also allows constant time adding and removing at either end, and a constant time length getter.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-collection/LinkedList-class.html

So what it means is that if we do have an reference to a given element, we can put a new element to our `LinkedList` if this new element are inserted right before or after our current element.

Since a reference to a `LinkedList` itself has a reference to the first and last element (since it is doubled-linked), it also means we can insert an element at the beginning or end of the list if we just have a reference to the `LinkedList` itself.

But if we want to insert at an arbitrary index, we need to iterate over each element until we get the position we want to insert at. This operation require linear time since we cannot just jump to a specific position (like with normal `List`).

So no, Dart does not handle `LinkedList` (Double-linked) differently from other double-linked list implementations. Which is also what the documentation describes.